# Unity SkinnedMeshRender: is there a way to cache mesh and restore later?

Tags: unity, mesh, skinning

In unity, I'm writing a script that deforms a mesh associated with a SkinnedMeshRenderer pretty significantly. However, at some point, I'd like to reset it back to particular states. I'd like the ability to both reset to its original position, and an intermediate position.

Right now, I've tried baking the mesh:

```
Mesh originalMesh = new Mesh();
skinnedMeshRenderer.BakeMesh(originalMesh);
```

But when I then try to restore it:

```
skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh = originalMesh;
```

It doesn't seem to behave as I would have expected.

I've also tried:

```
Mesh originalMesh = skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh;
//deform sharedMesh
skinnedMeshRenderer = originalMesh;
```

but this does nothing since it seems to be just storing a reference.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Just to add detail, I want to take a snapshot of all the verticies, weights, blendshapes, etc. And then restore everything back to the snapshot at a later moment in time. I can reset the blendshapes fine, but the mesh seems to be messed up.

Comment: Did you try instantiating the mesh, to get a copy of it rather than a reference to the one you're modifying?

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: `originalMesh = Instantiate(skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh);` no?

Comment: OH! I didn't know you could do that. Looks promising. I'll post later on after testing it out

Comment: That worked great! thanks. Know any way to also restore bones?

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an answer. If you have a new question to ask about bones, I recommend posting it separately so it can attract its own answers.

Comment: @DMGregory After profiling a bit in the full program, I noticed that instantiating the mesh takes around 300ms. I tested by instantiating 10 times and measured avg time. Do you know of any ways that are more performant? I need to do this periodically at runtime, not just during load. Right now this introduces a frame rate drop on a very powerful computer. Just a note that the mesh has ~7000 vertices.

Comment: Have you tried making a new mesh and just setting the vertex/texcoord/normals/triangles arrays, and comparing how that performs?

Comment: Yes that was much faster to cache these arrays using myArray.CopyTo(destination, 0); then copy them back in. thanks. I'll update solution.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @DMGregory 's helpful comments, here is my solution:

---

To Cache (called in `OnEnable()`):

```
        void CacheMeshAndSkeleton() {
            if (originalBonePositions == null) {
                originalBonePositions = new Vector3[skinnedMeshRenderer.bones.Length];
                for (int boneIndex = 0; boneIndex < skinnedMeshRenderer.bones.Length; boneIndex++) {
                    originalBonePositions[boneIndex] = skinnedMeshRenderer.bones[boneIndex].position;
                }
            }
            if (originalMesh == null) originalMesh = skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh;
            skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh = Instantiate(originalMesh);          
        }
```

Note that the null-check isn't really needed. For me it was, since I'm running the script in edit mode using `[ExecuteInEditMode]`, and edit mode seems to call OnEnable more than once, so I needed to prevent it from overwriting the original mesh with a deformed one.

---

To Reset:

```
        void ResetMeshAndSkeleton() {
            for (int boneIndex = 0; boneIndex < originalBonePositions.Length; boneIndex++) {
                skinnedMeshRenderer.bones[boneIndex].position = originalBonePositions[boneIndex];
            }
            skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh = Instantiate(originalMesh);
            // Note that it seems to me that order might be important here. 
            // If you reset the the Mesh first, when you move the bones back, 
            // it will apply linearblendskinning to the mesh and deform it to the bone positions. 
            // Not sure why this matters, but seemed to in my testing
        }
```

This seems to work great!

UPDATE:

I found an increase in performance by instead caching the mesh's arrays (vertices, etc) and swapping them back to restore.

I used the CopyTo array function. `sourceArray.CopyTo(destinationArray, 0);` where 0 is the index to start copying from.

In my case I was only manipulating the vertices, the tris, normals, etc were never altered, so just copying this one array saved a huge amount of performance vs. instantiation.

Comment: Great observation about the improved performance when just copying the array. I'd speculate that this saves the work of allocating a new GPU-side buffer for all the mesh details and uploading data to it, since your array copy stays CPU-side.